# How do I select which folder to sync?

Tags: ubuntu-one

My Ubuntu One account is nearly full with various folders for almost 5GB.

On the computer I'm working on, my /home does not have even half that space. Since I only need a few folder for my current work, how can I select these only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the U1 control panel and you can choose which folder to synchronize locally and which not. 
By default when you start to use U1 there is no folder synchronized except UbuntuOne folder. So you can select which folder to download to your PC.

Comment: It turns out that I had several copies of my folders and that confused me. It's working now, thank you!